# Use a plain list instead of a list of tuples when specifying "choices" for a Django model or form field?

Tags: django

Can you use a plain list instead of a list of tuples when specifying "choices" for a Django model or form field?

So instead of specifying a tuple choices list like 
(("", ""),)

Could you specify a single item list where the display and stored value are identical?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

```
..., choices=tuple((x, x) for x in L), ...
```

Comment: Doesn't zip(L, L) do the same thing with more brevity?

Comment: Sure, you can use that if you like, provided that `L` isn't actually an iterator.